# Unrecognized column name in bq command line. How can I solve?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I'm trying to get a data in bigquery command line.
In google cloud platform, It works well.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dd.dd.concept AS SELECT concept_id, concept_name, domain_id, vocabulary_id,
    concept_class_id,
    'concept' AS load_table_id,
    FARM_FINGERPRINT(GENERATE_UUID()) AS load_row_id
FROM
    dd.dd.tmp_concept;
```

But, when I execute in big query command line, the error occurs.

Starting query...

> Waiting on bqjob_r53a353d670b4b048_00000186e0f6d6a2_1 ... (0s) Current
> status: DONE Error in query string: Error processing job
> dd:bqjob_r53a353d670b4b048_00000186e0f6d6a2_1': Unrecognized name:
> concept_id at [1:65]

In command line, the command starts like this.

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dd.dd.concept AS SELECT concept_id, concept_name, domain_id, vocabulary_id,
    concept_class_id,
    'concept' AS load_table_id,
    FARM_FINGERPRINT(GENERATE_UUID()) AS load_row_id
FROM
    dd.dd.tmp_concept;"
```

Is there anything different doing google cloud platform or in big query command line?

I'd tried in google cloud platform and in big query command line

Comment: I proposed you an answer, have you solved your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `bq query` execute a `BigQuery` job like for the queries executed from the console.

`bq query` used the `gcloud` cli and you have to be sure your `gcloud` is authenticated in the expected GCP project.

Check the authentication with the following command :

```bash
gcloud config list
```

You can set `gcloud` on the expected project if needed :

```bash
gcloud config set project myProject
```

Also a detail than can help, I think it's better using single quote around the query to be able to add character like ` in the query according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool)

```bash
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \
'SELECT
  word,
  SUM(word_count) AS count
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data`.samples.shakespeare
WHERE
  word LIKE "%raisin%"
GROUP BY
  word'
```